# Is it better to have 2 simple versions of a software or 1 complicated version?

Tags: organization, code-organization, project-organization

This is a simple question. Is it better to have 2 versions of code or one? One would be an engineering version that is not V&V tested with lots of functionality the other being a stripped-down customer version that is highly regulated and highly tested.

I have a simple problem, my code base is ballooning as new engineering features are demanded. However, the core customer code is extremely simple. The engineering portions sometimes cause unexpected bugs in the customer code. Also, every engineering bug has to be debugged and treated the same as a customer one which gives longer lead times for releases.

I see it as good and bad to split. First, it would allow engineering functions to be quickly made and released with no need to V&V test the software. The second advantage would be fewer and higher quality releases of customer-facing software. However, it would mean 2(smaller) codebases to maintain.

What is the common solution to this problem? Is there limit to which you decide it is time to break into two versions? Or should I just learn even more in-depth organizational techniques? I already try my best to follow the best organizational tips for the software and follow OOP best practices.

As of now, I would say my code base is about 50% customer software and 50% engineering functionality. However, I just got a new (large) engineering/manufacturing project to add to the software.

Any experience would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Split it.

---

You can use either of the models that you mention. It's about how you see it grow in the future and how it is presently set up.

If you decide to go the one large code base route, I would suggest that you use the `MVC` Architecture as it effectively sorts one large code base into smaller more manageable parts. This allows for a layer of abstraction for the engineers where they can easily narrow down a issue to it's own team. This allows for one team to not have to worry about how the other implemented a feature; is: the Graphic team does not need to worry about how the data is stored on your servers.

If you decide to go with the multiple code bases, you add an additional layer of "difficulty". You now have to maintain "twice" as much code. You will also need to make sure that the two sources play nice with each other. The benefit of doing it this way would be that you completely isolate the engineering version from your production version.

In your case, since you mention that the split is currently 50/50 between the 2 versions, I would recommend that you split the customer and the engineering version. This isolates the engineering code that is not tested form the customer code which is properly tested. This does give you "more" code to control but this issue can easily be mitigated by having 2 teams, each responsible for their own version.